# Abrir sesion (login) en otra web con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, login

Quiero saber si es posible acceder automaticamente a una web (hacer login) usando javascript.

Logicamente la idea es que el script ademas de iniciar sesion guarde la coki para mantenerla abierta.

Soy nuevo es esto no se si puedan hechar una mano con ejemplos.

Uno que intente sin exito en php usando de ejemplo Facebook.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Login</TITLE>
<script>
<!--
function login() {
document.form.action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php";
document.form.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="login()">
<FORM NAME="form" METHOD="GET">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="TuUsuarioAqui">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="password" VALUE="TUpasswordaqui">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Y un codigo que encontre de jquery pero no comprendi mucho.

```
// dont forget to include jQuery code
// preferably with .noConflict() in order not to break the site scripts
if (window.location.indexOf("mail.google.com") > -1) {
    // Lets login to Gmail
    jQuery("#Email").val("youremail@gmail.com");
    jQuery("#Passwd").val("superSecretPassowrd");
    jQuery("#gaia_loginform").submit();
}
```

Comment: Es muy amplia tu pregunta lee [ask] y edita tu pregunta detallando que es lo que necesitas o quieres realizar, porque se puede hacer una validación con JS y puedes guardar la sesión en LocalStorage y puedes hacer uso de esa clave-valor del usuario que hizo login, pero especifica mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Si la web, y el formulario de login en cuestión no tienen protección CSRF puede hacerse.